# Microsoft Graph API - GET Grading 'maxPoints' for Assignment

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-edu

I'm using the Microsoft Graph API with Laravel and attempting to pull a classes assignments with their grading points - the `maxPoints` property. The endpoint for this is `/education/classes/{classID}/assignments`

I can successfully call the data and dump it which returns the following data.

```
[
  "id" => "*****-****-****-****-*********"
  "classId" => "*****-****-****-****-*********"
  "displayName" => "Encryption and Decryption"
  "dueDateTime" => "2018-10-29T12:30:00Z"
  "status" => "assigned"
  "grading" => [
    "@odata.type" => "#microsoft.graph.educationAssignmentPointsGradeType"
    "maxPoints" => 100
  ]
]
```

The grading gets returned with its odata type set to the type `EducationAssignmentPointsGradeType` class and the `maxPoints` property is available. This is where I get stuck. I then loop through the data in the view using:

```
@foreach($assignments as $assignment)
  {{ $assignment->getGrading()->getMaxPoints() }} 
@endforeach
```

However this returns the following error:

```
Call to undefined method Microsoft\Graph\Beta\Model\EducationAssignmentGradeType::getMaxPoints()
```

The `getGrading()` method is of type `EducationAssignmentGradeType`. I'm not sure how to fetch `maxPoints` from this however, as the `EducationAssignmentGradeType` class has **no methods** in it. The `EducationAssignmentPointsGradeType` class however, has the `getMaxPoints` method available.

How would I go about calling the `getMaxPoints` method?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem here is that the [Microsoft Graph SDK](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php) only supports `/v1.0` and [Assignments](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/educationassignment) is currently only available in the `/beta` endpoint.

You seem to be [using the Beta models](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php/wiki/Using-Beta-Models) but my experience with these have been, at best, hit-or-miss. Looking at the [`EducationAssignmentGradeType` model](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php/blob/beta/src/Beta/Model/EducationAssignmentGradeType.php), it doesn't look like the models have been updated since `maxPoints` was rolled out to the beta (it's also missing `points` in the `EducationAssignmentPointsGrade` model as well.

Comment: I'm hoping we will have a beta SDK for .Net very soon..... fingers crossed!